# How to reference properties files in executable jar AND Eclipse?

Tags: java, executable-jar

I use two properties files: `log4j.properties` and `myapp.properties`. I want to load them correctly when I execute my application in Eclipse AND in an executable jar.

ATM the files are stored here: `/src/configs/*.properties`. I reference them in my code with this line:

```
config = new PropertiesConfiguration(getClass().getResource("/configs/myapp.properties"));
```

This works great if I execute my application in Eclipse, but fails if I execute the (from eclipse generated) executable jar. I have created a manifest file in `/META-INF/` and wrote this line into it:

```
Class-Path: .
```

To effect, executing the jar still fails :-( Where do I have to put my properties files and how do I have to reference them?

**Is it also possible to reference them outside the jar if I execute the jar and inside my project if I'm in Eclipse?**
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way you try to load the properties file looks fine to me. Have you checked if the properties files are actually part of the generated jar file?

Comment: I've opened the jar file and it looks a bit wired :-) First thing is that I could not open it with a normal unzip program (not allowed). Maybe the problem is the creation with Eclipse?!

Comment: So you can execute the jar (up to the point where your application fails to load the properties file) but not open its contents in zip tool like 7-zip? If you can run it, you should be able to unzip it. Unless maybe the jar file is still locked. Is you application still running? And what is the exception you get when the application fails to load the properties files?

Comment: Now I looked into it with jar -tvf... the best thing to do would be storing the properties files outside the jar I think

Answer (score 0):

Usually property files are meant to be deployed / modified without rebuilding the jar, e.g. environment / external resource specific things, hence they are stored separately.

But in case you have a need to keep them inside, make sure that (in your case) "configs/myapp.properties" are actually at the JAR's root level. Just unjar that jar you created to see what is there. Or you can run:

```
jar -tvf your.jar | grep myapp.properties
```

to see the actual path within a JAR without unjaring it.

If it is there, you can load them via a `classloader` as follows:

```
ClassLoader cl = YourClass.class.getClassLoader()

config = new PropertiesConfiguration( cl.getResourceAsStream( "configs/myapp.properties" ) ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint! As you said the properties files should be deployed without rebuilding the jar (I've updated my answer). How can I do this?

Comment: sure, just add them to your classpath => as a classpath resource. Usually you would have "src/main/java" and "src/main/resources" in your classpath ( if it is a classic maven structure ), so you can just copy your `configs` directory under "src/main/resources". Or just add a root of where `configs` live to Eclipse classpath: right click on the project, choose "Build Path" => "Configure Build Path", choose "Source". Add it there.